# How to find out whether a string is a path or an url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, path, pyqt5

I am working on a podcast application with PyQt5. The user can enter an url or path to an RSS file to add a new podacst. I need to be able to differentiate between an url and a path, because you cannot read a local file the same way as a file on some webserver. Additionally, I need to know if it is a path or an URL because I would like to show the user the file was not founf when it's a path. If I just try to open the path as a file, and try it as an URL when the file i not found, I would show the user that the url was not found, thought he wanted to open a file on his PC that doesn't exist. How can I find out whether a string is a path or an url using Python's standard library and, optionally, PyQt5 ?

Note : I added the PyQt5 tag because I would accept a solution using PyQt5's `QUrl`, `QFile`, etc. would be, er, good, for me.

Comment: Just try to access it as a file and see if it fails.

Comment: One thing is knowing that a text has a path format does not imply that it is a valid path. In Qt the urls can also be local paths with the scheme "file:"

Comment: @ekhumoro I edited my question; please reread it to understand why your solution would not work for me.

Comment: @Programmer On my system, I can take the exact url of this webpage and execute `mkdir -p 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66800035/how-to-find-out-whether-a-string-is-a-path-or-an-url'`. This will happily create five leaf-directories without error. Therefore, it is both a valid internet url *and* a valid (relative) file-system path. If you allow users to enter arbitrary input strings, you cannot really avoid [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) issues - hence my initial comment.

Comment: @ekhumoro hm, I get your point ... But then, how _could_ I do to show the user a file-not-found message when he meant to open a file, and an url-not-found when the server returned 404 ?

Comment: @Programmer You could prevent the user entering any relative urls or relative file-paths, and then use e.g. urlparse to also check whether the input has a plausible url scheme (i.e. not `""`, `"file"`, `"C"`, etc). Of course, an even simpler approach would be to have different entry widgets for urls and file-paths, and then store the inputs as distinct datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyQt5 it's still python code and i don't think it's a PyQt5 problem to solve.You can achieve this pretty easy with python either with:

- Checking if there is http or https or whatever in the url with regex.
- Or ping the site with os or urlopen or another library.

Probably there are other methodologies too.Basic example with urllib:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('a pc path')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='a pc path', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('http://google.com')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='google.com', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
```